# VS Code hangs on Workspace Trust

Tags: installation, workspace, trust

i installed the latest version of VS Code (1.57) but when i start it it hangs and wouldn't let me click the Workspace Trust dialogue. i tried removing and installing but still the same issue, even older versions. i am using Linux Sentos and it was working just fine before.

[Workspace trust screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adg7j.png)

Cheers